# How to activate a Maven profile per pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I have a large Maven project with one master module and lots of children, organized in a nice tree structure. However, some of the modules need special settings which would cause misbehaviour in other modules. For example, there are modules which do stuff on Hadoop which need a Java source level of 1.7, all other Java modules use a source level of 1.8, and now Scala modules are introduced into this tree which compile with `scala-maven-plugin` which needs special settings for `maven-compiler-plugin` when compiling mixed Java/Scala modules.

In the past I simply had a master module for the Hadoop stuff which defined the source level of 1.7 and added all necessary Hadoop dependencies. Now I want to avoid defining another master module for Hadoop stuff written in Scala, and yet another module for Non-Hadoop stuff in Scala. I thought I could use profiles, so I defined two profiles in my master POM:

- `java` activates the `maven-javadoc-plugin`
- `scala` does not activate `maven-javadoc-plugin` but the `maven-scala-plugin` and configures it like in [the example from its documentation](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html)

In the master POM, the `java` profile is set as active by default, as Java is the default. When a project uses Scala, I want to activate the `scala` profile, and deactivate `java`, but setting `activeByDefault` to `false` for the `java` profile has no effect, causing compile errors.

So, is there a way to enable a profile specific to a module without having to set it manually in each pom?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you want to activate profile from child pom based on its configuration. I'm afraid it is not possible. However you can reorganize project tree structure to take advantage of pom inheritance:

`pom.xml // general properties for all projects
|-- java-modules
|   -- pom.xml // inherits from master pom, configures maven-compile-plugin
|   -- java-8-modules
|      -- pom.xml // inherits from java-modules pom, uses java 8 compiler
|         -- java-8-project-a
|   -- java-7-modules
|      -- pom.xml // inherits from java-modules pom, uses java 7 compiler
|         -- java-7-project-a
|-- scala-modules
    -- pom.xml // inherits from master pom, configures maven-scala-plugin 
       -- scala-project-a`

You write one master pom for all modules in top directory, child poms just specify java/scala details.

More about pom inheritance https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure maven profile for each project(module) then you have to add profile setting in the project(module) pom.xml file

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <jdk>1.4</jdk>
    </activation>
    <your properties goes here>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Also if you do not want to execute some profile then you have to add

```
    mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P !profile-1,!profile-2
```

in the project pom.xml file

Comment: That means, when I have modules A, B, and C, and A and B use the Java profile and C uses the Scala one, I have to add these profiles individually to all modules?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use profile, Mateusz Balbus answer, that is define nested pom-packaged project that define java and scala modules respectively